# How can I correctly use the stream map() in this use case involving the conversion of an entity class instance into a DTO instance?

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, java-stream, java-14

I am working on a Spring Boot application and I am trying to use a more modern (Java 8+ constructs) but I am finding some difficulties trying to implement the following changes to my existing code.

I have the following service method:

```
@Override
public Optional<User> activateDeactivateUser(int userId, boolean isActive) throws NotFoundException {
    
    Optional<User> retrievedUser = this.userRepository.findById(userId);
    
    if(retrievedUser.isEmpty())
        throw new NotFoundException(String.format("The user having ID or email %s was not found", userId));
    
    
    return Optional.ofNullable(retrievedUser) 
            .map((user) -> { 
                log.info(String.format("****** USER E-MAIL *******", user.get().getEmail()));
                
                user.get().set_active(isActive);
                this.userRepository.save(user.get());
                
                return user;
                })
            .orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(String.format("The user having ID or email %s was not found", userId)));
}
```

As you can see this method return an **Optional** object. As first thing I am not sure that returning an **Optional** is a good practice (because if it is empty I am throwing and handling a **NotFoundException**).

But the main problem is that my **User** class is an entity class (I am using Hibernate so it contains the table mapping) I want to change the previous method in order to retrive an **UserDTO** object.

In order to convert an **User** instance to an **UserDTO** instance I have this **ConversionService** injected into my service class (I used it elsewhere)

```
@Autowired
ConversionService conversionService;
```

My main problem is that in my previous method I am using the **map()** operator. I have tried to change the previous service method in this way:

```
@Override
public UserDTO activateDeactivateUser(int userId, boolean isActive) throws NotFoundException {
    
    Optional<User> retrievedUser = this.userRepository.findById(userId);
    User userToBeUpdated = null;
    
    if(retrievedUser.isEmpty())
        throw new NotFoundException(String.format("The user having ID or email %s was not found", userId));
    else
        userToBeUpdated = retrievedUser.get(); 
    
    return userToBeUpdated
            .map((userToBeUpdated) -> { 
                log.info(String.format("****** USER E-MAIL *******", userToBeUpdated.getEmail()));
                
                userToBeUpdated.set_active(isActive);
                this.userRepository.save(userToBeUpdated);
                
                return userToBeUpdated;
                })
            .orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(String.format("The user having ID or email %s was not found", userId)));

}
```

My idea was to use the **map()** method in order to transform one object (my **User** object into an **UserDTO** object and save it on the DB applying a function).

First of all Eclipse it is giving me the following error on the **map()** method call:

> The method map(( userToBeUpdated) -> {}) is undefined for the
> type User

Since I have few experience with stream I have no idea if it is a proper use case of the **map()** use. This because (also in the first method implementation, that worked fine) I am not implementing a real object transformation but I am changing the value of an object field and then I am saving it into the DB. In this second scenario (my second version of my service method) I have to transform from **User** to **UsertDTO**.

What am I missing? Is it legit to use **map()** for this use case or is it forcing the way that was intended the map()? What could be a good solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example the `if` statement is entirely pointless. You can entirely drop it, since the `map` on the `Optional` will be executed if there is an actual value returned which is not `null`. Also, there is a code duplication for the `NotFoundException`.

```
@Override
public UserDTO activateDeactivateUser(int userId, boolean isActive) throws NotFoundException {
    return this.userRepository.findById(userId)
            .map((userToBeUpdated) -> {
                log.info(String.format("****** USER E-MAIL *******", userToBeUpdated.getEmail()));

                userToBeUpdated.set_active(isActive);
                this.userRepository.save(userToBeUpdated);

                return userToBeUpdated;
            })
            .orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(String.format("The user having ID or email %s was not found", userId)));

}
```

Although, this code might work, the problem with this is that we have a side-effect inside the lambda in the `map`. It is recommended to have pure functions  when we pass it as a higher-order function for a mapping operation. It would probably be better to go with something like this:

```
@Override
public User activateDeactivateUser(int userId, boolean isActive) throws NotFoundException {

    User retrievedUser = this.userRepository.findById(userId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(String.format("The user having ID or email %s was not found", userId)));

    retrievedUser.set_active(isActive);
    this.userRepository.save(retrievedUser);

    return retrievedUser;
}
```

Now, your second example is more problematic. This snippet is invalid and logically makes no sense:

```
userToBeUpdated
            .map((userToBeUpdated) -> {...})
```

`User` class is a hibernate entity, which most likely does not have a `map` method implemented on it, why would it? In Java usually streams and optionals offer implementation for a `map`. It is used apply some transformation to each object encapsulated by the stream/optional. You would want to check out the docs for [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) and [optionals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) to read more about them.

What I believe you want to do here is the following:

```
@Override
public UserDTO activateDeactivateUser(int userId, boolean isActive) throws NotFoundException {

    User retrievedUser = this.userRepository.findById(userId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(String.format("The user having ID or email %s was not found", userId)));

    retrievedUser.set_active(isActive);
    this.userRepository.save(retrievedUser);

    return conversionService.convert(retrievedUser);
}
```

I expect that the `ConversionService` has something like a `convert` method, which takes an entity object and returns a DTO.

Some other notes unrelated to the question:

- Please adhere the Java coding standards. In Java, we do not use snake case for method calls. This `userToBeUpdated.set_active(isActive);` should be something like this `userToBeUpdated.setActive(isActive);`